# Stop Internal javascript waiting for External Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, loading, wait

Hi I have a web page with a fair bit of javascript on it, which is running perfectly well. I have a small panel showing my Latest Tweets from twitter.com My problem is that all the other javascript on the page it waiting for the twitter badge to go and get all the info it needs from twitters server before they render. This creates a 3-4 second gap before everything all the js is loaded. Is there anyway around this?

The javascript I'm using to pull info from twitter is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/usernamehere.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=3"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the script at the bottom of the page.

Or load the script dynamically after the document is ready.

Or use HTML async script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="blabla" async="async"></script>
```

Comment: That `async` attribute is not yet widely supported. Moreover, it should either just be present (`async` or set to an empty string: `async=""`) or set to its own canonical name (`async="async"`), but not `true`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html#boolean0

Comment: @Marcel, very well, seems the information I read on w3schools was misleading.

Comment: I hate to say this and I don't want to start a rant on them, but I saw many tutorials on w3schools (anyway *not* related to W3C) that contain flaws.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default widget, there is a newer version that is nicer on your page load. Get it at http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

If you want to load JSON data yourself, get jQuery (http://jquery.com) and use $(document).ready() to start loading when the rest of the page has (almost) finished rendering.